# Setting controller IP in Ryu for physical switch

Tags: sdn, openvswitch, ryu

I am new to Ryu and trying to set it up with a physical switch connected to a VM on my computer. The switch's controller is set to 10.0.1.8 and I am trying to set the same on ryu controller. I used the following commands:

```
    sudo ovs-vsctl add-br br0
    sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth2
    sudo ovs-vsctl set bridge br0 10.0.1.8 protocols=OpenFlow13
```

Doing a netstat shows that ryu controller is still listening on 0.0.0.0 as per the output below. Can someone please assist me here?

```
    State       PID/Program name
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6633            0.0.0.0:*
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had to include the --ofp-listen-host parameter and specify the controller IP there, as follows:

```
    PYTHONPATH=. ./bin/ryu-manager --verbose --ofp-listen-host 10.0.1.8 ryu/app/simple_switch.py
```

The commands I was using earlier apply only to a Mininet topology.

Answer (score 0):

```
ovs-vsctl -- \
    --id=@s1c0 create Controller target=\"tcp:10.0.1.8:6633\" max_backoff=1000 -- \
    --id=@s1-listen create Controller target=\"ptcp:6654\" max_backoff=1000 -- \
    --if-exists del-br s1 \
        -- add-br s1 \
        -- set bridge s1 controller=[@s1c0,@s1-listen] other_config:datapath-id=0000000000000001 fail_mode=secure other-config:disable-in-band=true protocols=OpenFlow13 other-config:dp-desc=s1 \
```